# Problem MYSQL Query join with output want

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I has problem with MySql query. I has try many time for query, but still not get what I want. Maybe anyone can help my problem.

This is structure table and what output I want :
[image: display table and output I want]

This is whats i try, but when @IDPERIODS=2, thats not show i want :

```
SET @IDPERIODS:=2;
SELECT billing.*
    FROM _t_data_user
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id as iduser,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_setting_bill,ifnull(b.id_setting_bill,a.id_setting_bill)) as idsettingbill,
    id_user_group as group_user,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_bill_type, ifnull(b.id_bill_type,a.id_bill_type)) as idbilltype,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_period, ifnull(b.id_period,a.id_period)) as period,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.amount_bill, ifnull(b.amount_bill,a.amount_bill)) as amount_billing
        FROM _t_data_user
        LEFT JOIN _t_setting_bill_user b ON b.id_group_user=id_user_group and b.id_period=@IDPERIODS
        LEFT JOIN _t_setting_bill_user a ON a.id_user=user_id and a.id_period=@IDPERIODS
        WHERE IFNULL(a.id_period, b.id_period) = @IDPERIODS
    ) billing ON iduser = user_id
    WHERE period = @IDPERIODS
GROUP BY user_id, idbilltype
```

This MySql table scheme :

Table structure and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `_t_data_user` (
          `user_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `id_user_group` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `_t_data_user` (`user_id`, `id_user_group`)
    VALUES
        (1, 1),
        (2, 1),
        (3, 1),
        (4, 2);

CREATE TABLE `_t_setting_bill_user` (
          `id_setting_bill` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `id_group_user` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
          `id_user` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
          `id_period` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
          `id_bill_type` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
          `amount_bill` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id_setting_bill`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
        
INSERT INTO `_t_setting_bill_user` 
 (`id_setting_bill`, `id_group_user`, `id_user`,
  `id_period`, `id_bill_type`, `amount_bill`)
    VALUES
        (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1000),
        (2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 500),
        (3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 900),
        (4, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1000),
        (5, 1, 0, 2, 2, 500),
        (6, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1100);
```

Comment: You should explain your output and add your sample data. A picture doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot it, thank you, i has update it

Comment: Here's what I discovered, for `@IDPERIODS=2` the missing row is actually matching the first row of `b`. This is why it doesn't show in the result. You can get it to show if you're using `UNION ALL`. The problem is though, the query will return the extra row when you look for `@IDPERIODS=1` (one being mentioned by Caius Jard).

Comment: Yes, true, thats problem if using union. So i'm confused  I think, condition is like if userid not 0 using userid, if userid 0 using groupuserid. But i still cannot get result i want

Comment: I think columns variously described as `id_user`, `user_id`, `id_group_user`, and `id_user_group` will in time drive you nuts. My head hurts already.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the raw data you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  setting_bill_user s 
  JOIN data_user d 
  ON 
    s.id_group_user = d.id_user_group OR 
    s.id_user = d.user_id
```

Look:

[image]

**You just have to choose and alias the columns appropriately**

I can't work out why your desired output is missing the 1000 row for user id 1/setting bill 1, but I'm sure you can add some WHERE clause to cover that, whatever the reason may be

Comment: Hi thank your for answer, this cannot be what i want. I has try some with sub query still cannot, thats will dsiplay not like i want.

Comment: *this cannot be what i want* - in what way?

Comment: I added a graphic showing that the query does collate the raw data you want; and I highlighted in bold the bit where I pointed out the small bit of work you need to do to finish it off (choose and name your columns). Also, I've highlighted the latter thing I noted; for some reasons your desired data is missing one of the lines, but no reason is given for why; your question is lacking some detail that would explain this, so I've left it for you as a task to complete. I'd like to point out a reminder that SO is here to help you do your work, not take responsibility of doing your work for you

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xf1VmfYMbnGcabJS7dS6A1/0

Comment: I'm sorry, and thank you very much for answer, but i want like output with condition by period, see example on output image, so user_id 1 have two record only in idperiod 1

Comment: OK so that's the reason why "*your desired output is missing the 1000 row for user id 1/setting bill 1*" but what is the rule? You can't just say "i only want 2 per period" because then the question becomes **which 2?** i.e you must specifying which ones should be thrown away and *why*

Comment: Hi Caius, please see sample my query test in update question. I has try like that but output still not get i want (ex. using period 1 is ok, period 2 is not ok). thank you before.

Comment: Just tell me why I should throw away the 1000 and not the 500 or 900 for user 1. Why is the 1000 the bad one? Why is 500 not the bad one? Why is 900 not the bad one?

Comment: Example for userid 1, he have different amount from group user, if in setting_bill id_user is 0 and id_group_user not 0 so all user following setting_bill in id_group_user with same id_bill_type and id_period. Sorry if my explain is not good, i difficult to talk, thats esay on my pic i attach in above to see

Comment: So it seems to be that your rule is "if the user is in the output because they are joined on userid it is higher priority than the one that is joined by group id". 900 is higher priority than 1000 because 900 is `user_id = id_user` but 1000 is `id_group_user = id_user_group` ?

Comment: Do you use MySQL 8?

Comment: Yes, true, if no userid same, thats use groupid. I'm use mysql 5.5 in other using mariadb 10.

Comment: Any appetite for upgrading that? MySQL 5.5 is 10 years old now.. MySQL 8 has features that make this easy

Comment: Whats the feature? Can you teach me? So i can get output i want

Comment: Can you install mysql8? ROW_NUMBER OVER. it can be done in my5.5 but it involves more work, or hacks

Comment: Thank you, I think when hosted next i find mysql 8 but, any solution another using version mysql about?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that removing a few parts from the subquery will return the result that you're looking for:

```
SELECT billing.*
    FROM _t_data_user
    JOIN (
  SELECT user_id AS iduser,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_setting_bill,IFNULL(b.id_setting_bill,a.id_setting_bill)) AS idsettingbill,
    id_user_group AS group_user,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_bill_type, IFNULL(b.id_bill_type,a.id_bill_type)) AS idbilltype,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_period, IFNULL(b.id_period,a.id_period)) AS period,
    IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.amount_bill, IFNULL(b.amount_bill,a.amount_bill)) AS amount_billing
        FROM _t_data_user t
        LEFT JOIN _t_setting_bill_user b ON b.id_group_user=t.id_user_group
        LEFT JOIN _t_setting_bill_user a ON a.id_user=t.user_id 
        WHERE IFNULL(a.id_period, b.id_period) = @IDPERIODS
    ) billing ON iduser = user_id
GROUP BY user_id, idbilltype;
```

1. I've removed `AND id_period=@IDPERIODS` of the `ON` condition in both of `LEFT JOIN` in the subquery.
2. I've changed `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` in the outer query because you were doing `LEFT JOIN` with a `WHERE` condition on the data from the right reference (the subquery). Which, in practice is just a normal `JOIN` so `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary. Therefore, I also removed `WHERE period = @IDPERIODS` from the outer query.

And that's it. Other than that, most of your original query structures are still intact.

[Demo fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYekYovisq1BV81iQSK4Rg/0)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer, this is great. But when @IDPERIODS=2 any record result iduser with idperiod give value 1.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Are you referring to the result in the fiddle or from your local? IF it's in the fiddle, can you pinpoint which one is returning incorrect value?

Comment: i run in the fiddle, i see record number 2 with iduser 1, the period value is 1, should period value is 2

Comment: Ahh, I see. That part I didn't change anything. It's from your `SELECT ..` section in the subquery, particularly this part `IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_period, IFNULL(b.id_period,a.id_period)) AS period`. If you separate that part, and run them, you'll see that the `IF()`  condition doesn't match and since `b.id_period` returned `1` and it's not `NULL`, it returned `1` in the end result. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYekYovisq1BV81iQSK4Rg/1 .

Comment: ahh true, now the problem with the record data. Hi, do have idea maybe with the table structure for made easy? with the output i want. anyway big thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure. In your case, I don't think the table structure is the main issue but your condition requirement is what you need to refine. Maybe, instead of doing `IF(a.id_bill_type=b.id_bill_type,a.id_period, IFNULL(b.id_period,a.id_period)) AS period` , you can just directly input the `period` value with the variable you were looking for; so just do `@IDPERIODS AS period`. I mean, it is the period value that you want isn't it? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYekYovisq1BV81iQSK4Rg/3

Answer (score 0):

Halo bro desugha,
I think you should make it on programatic way, you should re-arrange and create object to combine data from data_user INTO setting_bill_user

```
 SELECT compacted_usr_bill.* FROM (
    SELECT billusr.*, 
        usr.user_id AS usr_id_usr, usr.id_user_group AS usr_id_group
    FROM (
        SELECT bill.id_setting_bill,
            CASE 
                WHEN bill.id_user > 0 AND bill.id_group_user = 0 THEN bill.id_user
                WHEN bill.id_user = 0 AND bill.id_group_user > 0 THEN bill.id_group_user
                ELSE bill.id_user
            END AS grouped_id_usr,
            bill.id_period, bill.id_bill_type, bill.amount_bill
            FROM _t_setting_bill_user AS bill) 
        AS billusr
    LEFT JOIN _t_data_user AS usr
        ON billusr.grouped_id_usr IN(usr.user_id, usr.id_user_group)        
    ) AS compacted_usr_bill
```

This query will combine them, you can filter again with Grouping or Programmatic way

Comment: hello bro, thank you very much for help me. But thats not like output result

Comment: yupe, it just a raw output, from that result you can JOIN another table to filter out with DISTINC Selecet or GROUPING